# Stop asp.net from escaping HTML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-entities

I'm trying to set asp:image AlternateText. The string I want to set it to contains HTML entities that are already escaped. But asp.net then escapes them again.

I'm setting it with a simple assignment statement. Basically:

```
imgBanner.AlternateText="Jos&eacute;"
```

But what I get in the source is actually

```
<img blah blah alt="Jos&amp;eacute;">
```

Which of course then displays as "Jos&eacute" rather than showing the accented "e".

Really the text is coming from a function that reads it from the database, but I can watch in the debugger and see that the text is correct when I read it from the DB, and if I examine the contents of AlternateText immediately after the assignment it is correct. But when it gets to the browser, it's all been double-escaped.

(P.S. No need to warn me about script injection attacks. The text in the database is entered by me. There is no way for a user to update this table. The reason for getting it from the DB is because I read different text depending on the language and other parameters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
imgBanner.AlternateText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Jos&eacute;")
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. Seems pretty goofy to decode it just so ASP can re-encode it, but it works.

Comment: Yes I agree it's goofy, but there seems to be no way to stop asp.net from encoding it in first place.